# Pull from a website and store the text as an array in JS

Tags: html, jquery, css, web-scraping

The title says most of what I've been trying to get my head around Jquery.
I've made a similar solution to what I want already, but the problem I have is that I don't want to assign it to an asset in my HTML. So, how would I goa about storing [this page](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VeryVhersty/Thealonic.html/main/Voreware%20Config) as an array, each line on the page being a new line in a variable?

Here's my current code I have with the purpose of being able to update all of my website patch notes without having to directly update the page, and it loading only when you want to read said page.

```
$.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VeryVhersty/Thealonic.html/main/patch%20logs', function(data) { $( "patchnotes" ).last().html( data ); }, 'text')
```

Any good pointers would be helpful to how jquery or data storing works. There's probably an identical post somewhere that can explain this to my dumb monkey brain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `fetch` here, in order to get the content of the page, then storing all the lines in an array, which you can access using `index` in an array or using a `loop` as I have commented in the code.

```js
    fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VeryVhersty/Thealonic.html/main/Voreware%20Config')
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(data => {
            const arrayOfWords = data.split('\n')
            arrayOfWords.forEach(line => {
                // here in line, in each iteration of the loop, the value of each line is stored
                console.log(line)
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
```

If you want to know more about [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Comment: Let me know if you have any issues with this!

Comment: Absolutely perfect, Thanks a lot! Stuff like this just gives me justification for being ignorant and avoiding jquery because in any other programming language there would only be a few tweaks to the regular page pull I showed. Not a massive fan from the little i've learned.

Comment: The same goes for me too, not a big fan of Jquery, I like vanilla JS more than Jquery. Glad that I was able to help!